# Trying to read wide char gives EOF

Tags: c, file, unicode, fopen, widechar

I've got a text file, `foo.txt`, with these contents:

```
R⁸2
```

I had a large program reading it and doing things with each character, but it always received EOF when it hit the `⁸`. Here's the relevant portions of the code:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

FILE *in = fopen(argv[1],"r");

while (1) {
    wint_t c = getwc(in);
    printf("%d ",wctob(c));

    if (c == -1)
        printf("Error %d: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));

    if (c == WEOF)
        return 0;
}
```

It prints `82 -1` (the ASCII codes for `R` and EOF). No matter where I have the `¹` in the file, it always reads as EOF. **Edit**, I added a check for `errno` and it gives this:

```
Error 84: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
```

However, ⁸ is [Unicode U+2078 'SUPERSCRIPT EIGHT'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2078/index.htm). I wrote it to `foo.txt` via `cat` and copy-pasting from fileformat.info. A hexdump of `foo.txt` shows:

```
0000000: 52e2 81b8 32                             R...2
```

What's the problem?

Comment: You need to check for `WEOF` instead of `EOF`, also change `int` to  `wint_t`. Take a look to the documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/getwc/

Comment: And the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k477bzh.aspx) for `int wctob(wint_t wchar);` too. *If `wctob` successfully converts a wide character, it returns its multibyte character representation, only if the multibyte character is exactly one byte long. If `wctob` encounters a wide character it cannot convert to a multibyte character or the multibyte character is not exactly one byte long, it returns a `–1`.*

Comment: @KeineLust done, updated.

Comment: Which OS and C compiler are you using? I think the combination of (OS, compiler, locale) is the issue. For example, your code runs fine on macOS using clang (with the issue mentioned by @WeatherVane that it will print -1 for the '⁸' character), that is, the output is `82 -1 50 10 -1`.

Comment: @idz Raspbian PIXEL 4.9.2, gcc 4.9, locale cleared using `setlocale(LC_ALL,"");`.

Comment: Looks like your input file is UTF-8, but your default locale is not.  What have you set `LC_CTYPE` and `LANG` environment variables to?

Comment: @ChrisDodd `locale`'s output is `LANG=C ... LC_CTYPE="C"`, the `...` denoting extraneous information.

Comment: Try using `C.UTF-8` or some other UTF-8 locale.  What does `locale -a` tell you are supported locales on your system?

Comment: @ChrisDodd Fixed! If you post that as an answer I'll accept. Also, do you know why `setlocale(LC_ALL,"");` didn't fix the problem? I was under the assumption that would portably set it to a codepage compatible with Unicode.

Comment: @MDXF `setlocale(LC_ALL,"");` is a way to set the default locale.  It existed before Unicode and so is not specified to be Unicode aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Check for `WEOF` instead of `EOF`

`EOF` is meant for single-byte characters. `WEOF` is for wide characters. When reading the start of a wide character with `getwc`, single-byte EOF can sometimes be returned.

In `stdio.h`:

```
#define EOF (-1)
```

In `wchar.h`:

```
#define WEOF (0xffffffffu)
```

#### 2. Set the locale to one supporting Unicode

The default locale of a C program is `C`, also called `POSIX`, which is only meant for ASCII. Using `setlocale`, it is sometimes necessary to explicitly set the appropriate locales to codepages that support Unicode. `C.UTF-8` is portable.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"C.UTF-8");
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"C.UTF-8");
```

#### 3. Use the proper type for wide characters

The return value of `getwc` isn't `char`, `int` or even `wchar_t`, it's `wint_t`. Make sure that your character variable `c` is of type `wint_t`, to avoid memory problems.