# Read and print special ascii characters from file in c

Tags: c, ascii

I want to know how to read special ascii character from txt file.

I have this text file and I want to print:

```
▄ ▀█   █     █   █▄    █▀
████  █   █  ███    █   ▄███▄ ██▄▄▄ ████▄
```

How can this be printed?  When go print it I get error. How fix?

I want to make mainmenu for game. Instead of print directly I want to type text file for flexibility. It supposed to print out "ASCII BASTILLE DAY" with 219th char but it too much of mess. I also try use batch file but it also does not work.

Here is the code:

````
void mainmenu()
{
    while (1) {
        if (mmplso <= 0) { PlaySound(TEXT("SFX\\VLVce.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC); mmplso = 50800; }
        cls();
        hidcur();


        /*
        printf("\n              Made by Mauser\n\n%d\n\n                VER(1.0A)\n\n", mmplso);
        //
        //
        // 
        //
        printf("\n       %c%c%c    %c%c%c  %c%c%c  %c%c%c%c%c %c%c%c%c%c\n", (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219);
        printf("      %c   %c  %c    %c   %c   %c     %c\n", (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219);
        printf("      %c%c%c%c%c   %c%c  %c       %c     %c\n", (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219);
        printf("      %c   %c %c   %c %c   %c   %c     %c\n", (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219);
        printf("      %c   %c  %c%c%c   %c%c%c  %c%c%c%c%c %c%c%c%c%c\n\n", (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219);
        //
        printf("%c%c%c%c   %c%c%c    %c%c%c %c%c%c%c%c %c%c%c%c%c %c     %c     %c%c%c%c%c\n", (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219,
            (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219);
        printf("%c   %c %c   %c  %c      %c     %c   %c     %c     %c\n", (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219);
        printf("%c%c%c%c  %c%c%c%c%c   %c%c    %c     %c   %c     %c     %c%c%c%c\n", (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219);
        printf("%c   %c %c   %c %c   %c   %c     %c   %c     %c     %c\n", (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219);
        printf("%c%c%c%c  %c   %c  %c%c%c    %c   %c%c%c%c%c %c%c%c%c%c %c%c%c%c%c %c%c%c%c%c\n\n", (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219), (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219;
        //
        printf("            %c%c%c%c   %c%c%c  %c   %c\n", (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219);
        printf("            %c   %c %c   %c %c   %c\n", (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219);
        printf("            %c   %c %c%c%c%c%c  %c %c\n", (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219);
        printf("            %c   %c %c   %c   %c\n", (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219);
        printf("            %c%c%c%c  %c   %c   %c\n\n\n", (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219, (char)219);
        //
        */


        printf("PRESS ANY KEY...");
        if (_kbhit()) { PlaySound(TEXT("SFX\\close.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC); break; }

        mmplso--;
    }
    system("cls");
}

void mainLoop()
{
    mmplso = 0;
    mainmenu();
    while (1)
    {
        Setup();
        mainGame();
    }
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(437);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(437);
    mainLoop();
    return 0;
}

```
````

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641439/trying-to-read-wide-char-gives-eof)

Comment: Unrelated: try [FIGlet](http://www.figlet.org/).

Comment: Those are not "special ASCII characters". ASCII is purely a 7-bit character set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is most likely not in the code but in the way you create your text file. When you copy charters you are using (like ▀█▄) from the web and paste it in the default Windows notepad it's using UTF-8 encoding which is UNICODE and what you need is extended ASCII. So, first off I recommend you to use [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v7.9.3/) and manually set code page of new text file to something like OEM 852. In notepad++ you do it like this:

> Encoding > Character Set > Central European > OEM 852

**After that**, when you paste your special characters in the notepad++, text file they will be saved as ASCII and not UNICODE.

After you have correctly created text file you can print it to console by calling function that looks like this:

```
void printMyFile(const char *fileName) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    char *buffer = (char *)calloc(size, sizeof(char));
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), size, file);
    fclose(file);
    printf(buffer);
    free(buffer);
}
```

Additionally if your console still show your characters wrongly you should include Windows.h

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

And call function

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(852);
```

once before you print anything to the console.
Wish you luck!

**EDIT 1:** I saw your new edit with your code, using SetConsoleOutputCP(437) is also ok and will work.

Comment: Unfortunately is doesn't work, but thank you for your help. I get an stream.valid() error in visual studio and in codeblocks it prints out  "Γûä". It still doesn't do anything, I followed your steps in correct order but nothing,. Thx for good function though

Comment: Could you, upload your text file to https://hexed.it/ so we can be absolutely sure that file is not a problem? It show you content of file byte by byte so you know exactly what is in the file.

Comment: Also, in visual studio you should add #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS as a first line if you are using fopen

Comment: I indeed have used _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. Also hexed.it was just a bunch of classic "Γυe" 's. The file only has (▀, █, ▄) and some plain, normal text

Comment: Ok, so if your file is like this https://pasteboard.co/JSrhyqX.png
Problem is probably in the console codepage. Could you run cmd and type command chcp that shows you default console codepage

Comment: The cmd says 437

Comment: And the code you posted in your edit, does it print "ASCII BASTILLE DAY" correctly or is it also a mess as it is when you print from a file?

Comment: Yup, it works. But if I want to make a change it will take literal hours to fix, so you know...

Comment: Yea I know i worked with lot of ASCII art for console games, GIFs, even videos and things like that, it can be peaty painful. From what I can see console is not the problem. So, could you please take screenshots of what https://hexed.it/ shows you is in the file and the screenshot of what you get as output in console. I want to be sure that I understand situation correctly.

Comment: I have no idea how to send a screenshot, let alone take one. That ain't an option. When I put the txt file that you instructed me to create into hexed.it, hexed.it displays the square like it should and the text in the file itself is a bunch of "ÛÛÛ    ÛÛÛ ÜÛÛÛÜ ßÛÛÛß ßÛÛÛß". The original file is a bunch of squares (what hexed.it should output) but when I put that through hexed.it its a bunch of "Γue".

Comment: "ÛÛÛ ÛÛÛ ÜÛÛÛÜ ßÛÛÛß ßÛÛÛß" is what you get when you open file in editor that uses windows-1250 as a codepage (like default windows notepad) but if you use notepad++ and set encoding to OEM 852 it will display it correctly as "███ ███ ▄███▄ ▀███▀ ▀███▀" so the data is the same the difference is just in representing it. So it's ok. But, I'm confused about "Γue" what do you think by that. Also if you can't screenshot, can you than copy-paste output that you get from the console when you try to print from the file.

Comment: I made a repository on github with little example code and example text file. So you can check if it's working for you as it works for me. It's Visual Studio project. https://github.com/momir64/Stackoverflow-answer

Comment: Wait, no. I think I got it working. I think its a visual studio problem. I did what you said in your answer a second time and it worked. Thank you for helping me through my dumbness

Comment: I'm very glad to hear that. Good luck with your future work!

Comment: Thanks! If we ever meet again I will give you a copy of the game :). Thank you for the knowledge!